# Let's get critical: Jul 2013 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sustainable Living Stack Exchange](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Final Results

- [Photo voltaic windows Pro - Cons. Where to get them?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/987/photo-voltaic-windows-pro-cons-where-to-get-them)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [What are the larger-scale options for storing rainwater?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/954/what-are-the-larger-scale-options-for-storing-rainwater)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [Which ecolabels take the whole life cycle of food products into account?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/969/which-ecolabels-take-the-whole-life-cycle-of-food-products-into-account)

  **Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Is there a cheap, sustainable alternative to newspapers for wrapping food?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/990/is-there-a-cheap-sustainable-alternative-to-newspapers-for-wrapping-food)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How much energy does it take to create a single light bulb?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/883/how-much-energy-does-it-take-to-create-a-single-light-bulb)

  **Net Score: -5** (Excellent: 0, Satisfactory: 1, Needs Improvement: 5)
- [Reusable vs. disposable diapers: which is better?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/907/reusable-vs-disposable-diapers-which-is-better)

  **Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 3)
- [What does it take to create an approbation label?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/909/what-does-it-take-to-create-an-approbation-label)

  **Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 0, Needs Improvement: 1)
- [Getting rid of those little flies (gnats) without using a spray?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/965/getting-rid-of-those-little-flies-gnats-without-using-a-spray)

  **Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How to recognize products with neonicotinoid pesticides in them?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/911/how-to-recognize-products-with-neonicotinoid-pesticides-in-them)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)
- [How do the criteria for 'best' building insulation change depending on context?](https://sustainability.stackexchange.com/questions/992/how-do-the-criteria-for-best-building-insulation-change-depending-on-context)

  **Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

Comment: I'm glad our scores are improving. Less posts with a negative rating compared to [the review in April](http://meta.sustainability.stackexchange.com/a/110/99)